# How to create plugins/addons for firefox, IE and chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, browser-plugin, browser-extension

I need to create plug-ins/add-ons for IE, firefox and chrome browsers for the following requirement:

If the url requested is in a particular format/ matching a particular regex pattern, the plugin has to block the request and pop up and alert box.

I have searched a lot but did not find anything helpful. For IE, I think we can create BHO for this purpose. But is there a way to achieve this using javascript?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Maggi

Comment: I wonder if the company that maggi6 works for is aware that browser plug-ins can be turned off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, IE's addon development is still very arcane compared to Firefox and Chrome for the behavior you're trying to accomplish.  You'll have to develop a BHO for IE whereas both Firefox and Chrome use Javascript as their addon platform.

http://www.enhanceie.com/ie/dev.asp is a great starting place for more information on how to develop extensions for IE.

Comment: To add to this: yes, you would need to write a BHO for IE.  There is no Javascript solution for IE.  It's C++ and COM all the way down.

Comment: Hi Villecoder,

Yes, EnhanceIE seems to be a good place to start for writing IE extenstions. Thanks so much for your response. I shall explore and try find a solution.

Regards,
Maggi