# How does Battlelog Game Manager work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I know that it uses a plugin but how does it work in Chrome etc? I can't explain it lol.

Basically I need something very similar to that but for one of my applications. So I have a website and when they visit a certain page I need it to send a function to the plugin I will be making and return some data. I have no clue how I should begin doing anything like this and was wondering if anyone here has any idea?

**------------EDIT-------------**
To make the question a bit easier is how can I go about creating a plugin for chrome which will allow me to run a application on the user computers like what Battlelog does.

Comment: You're going to have to give some context. What exactly does it do? Can you provide a link?

Comment: When the web pages loads I would like it to get some file names from a specified location on the users HDD. I updated the OP with a proper question. I was finding it hard to word it how I wanted it lol

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264816/how-to-create-plugins-addons-for-firefox-ie-and-chrome

Comment: I have made a simple extension before with Chrome but I don't think extensions have the ability to launch apps. I could be missing something thought.