# Chrome,Firefox,IE extension. Which language i need?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I need to develop 3 extensions. 1 for chrome, 1 for firefox, 1 for IE. I need start point. I know i can do that with javascript. But is javascript only way to develop chrome,firefox and ie extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For internet explorer, you might want to check this answer: [Developing Internet Explorer Extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643819/developing-internet-explorer-extensions)

For Firefox Extensions, you can either create [xul based extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Building_an_Extension), or the ones with the new [addon-sdk](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/Firefox-22/dev-guide/index.html). You can see a chart with a comparison [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/Firefox-22/dev-guide/guides/sdk-vs-xul.html).

In both cases, you work with javascript and xul or/and html and css.

For Google Chrome, you use javascript, html and css. For quick start links see the info page of [google-chrome-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-chrome-extension/info) page

Answer (score -1):

i think have to develop a BHO which is a module designed from Microsoft for Internet Explorer.it can be use in C# or C++ lanaguage

[XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL) is a based language for Mozilla  building user interfaces of applications extension. Check out [Firefox Extension Development Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions)

Comment: Chrome use HTML as a content markup language, CSS is used for styling, and JavaScript for scripting. You can check the following guide from Google 
[Developer Guide Chrome Extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devguide.html)

Comment: OP can check out this also
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264816/how-to-create-plugins-addons-for-firefox-ie-and-chrome

Comment: If you want to improve your answer you can edit the answer and add additional info instead of commenting.